# Magento domain error

Tags: admin

I have recently installed magento in my system.

Default url for magento when I installed was `localhost/magento`.
It was working fine and I have designed my website then I wanted to change my url name
I have logged into `localhost/magento/admin` 
in `settings/store/configure` I changed web url to `https://buyme/`
after I changed the url I saved the config from then the site is not opening

I am new to Magento and am not able to rectify this issue
Please someone help me.

Thank You.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: open database go to core_config_data table -> find %base_url% and change url there -> dont forget to add / after url

Comment: Remove cache via delete folder of /var from root directory and try to reload page.

Comment: ThankYou i got it

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Phpmyadmin->YourDb->core_config_data`

Then check values of

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
unicommon/general/url
```

if this values have url from the local.then change it to the actual url.
Don't forget to clear your cache.

Comment: ThankYou i got it